# Howto include clojure.spec'd functions in a test suite

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, generative-testing

Is there anyway to include clojure.spec'd functions in a generalized test suite? I know we can [register specs](http://clojure.org/guides/spec#_registry) and directly [spec functions](http://clojure.org/guides/spec#_spec_ing_functions).

```
(ns foo
  (:require [clojure.spec :as s]
            [clojure.spec.test :as stest]))

(defn average [list-sum list-count]
  (/ list-sum list-count))

(s/fdef average
        :args (s/and (s/cat :list-sum float? :list-count integer?)
                     #(not (zero? (:list-count %))))
        :ret number?)
```

And later, if I want to run generative tests against that spec'd function, I can use `stest/check`.

```
=> (stest/check `average)
({:spec #object[clojure.spec$fspec_impl$reify__14282 0x68e9f37c "clojure.spec$fspec_impl$reify__14282@68e9f37c"], :clojure.spec.test.check/ret {:result true, :num-tests 1000, :seed 1479587517232}, :sym edgar.core.analysis.lagging/average})
```

But ***i)*** is there anyway to include these test runs in my general test suite? I'm thinking of the kind of `clojure.test` integration that [test.check has](https://github.com/clojure/test.check#clojuretest-integration). The closest thing that I can see ***ii)*** is the `stest/instrument` (see [here](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec.test/instrument)) function. But that seems to just let us turn on checking at the repl. Not quite what I want. Also, ***iii)*** are function specs registered?

```
(defspec foo-test 
         100 

         ;; NOT this
         #_(prop/for-all [v ...]
           (= v ...))

         ;; but THIS
         (stest/some-unknown-spec-fn foo))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, solved this one. Turns out there's no solution out of the box. But some people on the clojure-spec slack channel have put together a `defspec-test` solution for **clojure.spec.test** and **clojure.test**.

So given the code in the question. You can **A)** define the `defspec-test` macro that takes your test name and a list of spec'd functions. You can then **B)** use it in your test suite.

Thanks Clojure community!! And hopefully such a utility function makes it into the core library.

**A)**

```
(ns foo.test
  (:require [clojure.test :as t]
            [clojure.string :as str]))

(defmacro defspec-test
  ([name sym-or-syms] `(defspec-test ~name ~sym-or-syms nil))
  ([name sym-or-syms opts]
   (when t/*load-tests*
     `(def ~(vary-meta name assoc
                       :test `(fn []
                                (let [check-results# (clojure.spec.test/check ~sym-or-syms ~opts)
                                      checks-passed?# (every? nil? (map :failure check-results#))]
                                  (if checks-passed?#
                                    (t/do-report {:type    :pass
                                                  :message (str "Generative tests pass for "
                                                                (str/join ", " (map :sym check-results#)))})
                                    (doseq [failed-check# (filter :failure check-results#)
                                            :let [r# (clojure.spec.test/abbrev-result failed-check#)
                                                  failure# (:failure r#)]]
                                      (t/do-report
                                        {:type     :fail
                                         :message  (with-out-str (clojure.spec/explain-out failure#))
                                         :expected (->> r# :spec rest (apply hash-map) :ret)
                                         :actual   (if (instance? Throwable failure#)
                                                     failure#
                                                     (:clojure.spec.test/val failure#))})))
                                  checks-passed?#)))
        (fn [] (t/test-var (var ~name)))))))
```

**B)**

```
(ns foo-test
  (:require [foo.test :refer [defspec-test]]
            [foo]))


(defspec-test test-average [foo/average])
```

Comment: I replaced the calls to `clojure.spec` with `clojure.spec.alpha`, and I'm using Clojure 1.9. The code doesn't catch errors... Do you have an updated version ?

Answer (score 4):

The above [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711634/5838486) can fail in the case where `:failure` is `false` due to how `stest/abbrev-result` tests for failure. See [CLJ-2246](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2246?focusedCommentId=47934&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-47934) for more details. You can work around this by defining your own version of `abbrev-result`. Also, the formatting of failure data has changed.

```clj
(require
 '[clojure.string :as str]
 '[clojure.test :as test]
 '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
 '[clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest])

;; extracted from clojure.spec.test.alpha
(defn failure-type [x] (::s/failure (ex-data x)))
(defn unwrap-failure [x] (if (failure-type x) (ex-data x) x))
(defn failure? [{:keys [:failure]}] (not (or (true? failure) (nil? failure))))

;; modified from clojure.spec.test.alpha
(defn abbrev-result [x]
  (let [failure (:failure x)]
    (if (failure? x)
      (-> (dissoc x ::stc/ret)
          (update :spec s/describe)
          (update :failure unwrap-failure))
      (dissoc x :spec ::stc/ret))))

(defn throwable? [x]
  (instance? Throwable x))

(defn failure-report [failure]
  (let [expected (->> (abbrev-result failure) :spec rest (apply hash-map) :ret)]
    (if (throwable? failure)
      {:type :error
       :message "Exception thrown in check"
       :expected expected
       :actual failure}
      (let [data (ex-data (get-in failure
                                  [::stc/ret
                                   :result-data
                                   :clojure.test.check.properties/error]))]
        {:type     :fail
         :message  (with-out-str (s/explain-out data))
         :expected expected
         :actual   (::s/value data)}))))

(defn check?
  [msg [_ body :as form]]
  `(let [results# ~body
         failures# (filter failure? results#)]
     (if (empty? failures#)
       [{:type    :pass
         :message (str "Generative tests pass for "
                       (str/join ", " (map :sym results#)))}]
       (map failure-report failures#))))

(defmethod test/assert-expr 'check?
  [msg form]
  `(dorun (map test/do-report ~(check? msg form))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly modified version of grzm's excellent answer that works with `[org.clojure/test.check "0.10.0-alpha4"]`. It uses the new `:pass?` key that comes from this PR: https://github.com/clojure/test.check/commit/09927b64a60c8bfbffe2e4a88d76ee4046eef1bc#diff-5eb045ad9cf20dd057f8344a877abd89R1184.

```clj
(:require [clojure.test :as t]
          [clojure.string :as str]
          [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
          [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest])

(alias 'stc 'clojure.spec.test.check)

;; extracted from clojure.spec.test.alpha
(defn failure-type [x] (::s/failure (ex-data x)))
(defn unwrap-failure [x] (if (failure-type x) (ex-data x) x))

;; modified from clojure.spec.test.alpha
(defn abbrev-result [x]
  (if (-> x :stc/ret :pass?)
    (dissoc x :spec ::stc/ret)
    (-> (dissoc x ::stc/ret)
        (update :spec s/describe)
        (update :failure unwrap-failure))))

(defn throwable? [x]
  (instance? Throwable x))

(defn failure-report [failure]
  (let [abbrev (abbrev-result failure)
        expected (->> abbrev :spec rest (apply hash-map) :ret)
        reason (:failure abbrev)]
    (if (throwable? reason)
      {:type :error
       :message "Exception thrown in check"
       :expected expected
       :actual reason}
      (let [data (ex-data (get-in failure
                                  [::stc/ret
                                   :shrunk
                                   :result-data
                                   :clojure.test.check.properties/error]))]
        {:type     :fail
         :message  (with-out-str (s/explain-out data))
         :expected expected
         :actual   (::s/value data)}))))

(defn check?
  [msg [_ body :as form]]
  `(let [results# ~body
         failures# (remove (comp :pass? ::stc/ret) results#)]
     (if (empty? failures#)
       [{:type    :pass
         :message (str "Generative tests pass for "
                       (str/join ", " (map :sym results#)))}]
       (map failure-report failures#))))

(defmethod t/assert-expr 'check?
  [msg form]
  `(dorun (map t/do-report ~(check? msg form))))
```

Usage:

```clj
(deftest whatever-test
  (is (check? (stest/check `whatever
                            ;; optional
                            {:clojure.spec.test.check/opts {:num-tests 10000}})))
```