# Howto include cljs.spec'd functions in a test suite (Redux)

Tags: clojurescript, clojure.spec, clojure-testing

I'm trying to wire into the `cljs.test` reporting system with a custom macro. I'm following the pattern in `cljs.test/deftest`:

- https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.test/deftest
- https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r1.10.773-2-g946348da/src/main/cljs/cljs/test.cljc#L230-L246

Copying and using deftest works just fine. But if I simply create my own test macro defspec-test, and return the results, I get the error `Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`. Anyone know what's going on here?

A variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697841/howto-include-clojure-specd-functions-in-a-test-suite/40711634) has come before (in Clojure). But now I'm trying to solve for Clojurescript and coming across this error.

*util.cljc*

```
(defmacro deftest2 [name & body]
  (when cljs.analyzer/*load-tests*
    `(do
       (def ~(vary-meta name assoc :test `(fn [] ~@body))
         (fn [] (cljs.test/test-var (.-cljs$lang$var ~name))))
       (set! (.-cljs$lang$var ~name) (var ~name)))))

(defmacro defspec-test [name sym-or-syms]
  (when cljs.analyzer/*load-tests*
    `(do
       (def ~(vary-meta name assoc :test `(fn [] ~sym-or-syms))
         (fn [] (cljs.test/test-var (.-cljs$lang$var ~name))))
       (set! (.-cljs$lang$var ~name) (var ~name)))))
```

*mytest.cljs*

```
(deftest2 zoobar
  (t/is (= 1 1)))

(defspec-test coocoobar
  (t/is (= 1 1)))
```

***Run results***

```
Testing mytest

ERROR in (coocoobar) (TypeError:NaN:NaN)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: #object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined]

Ran 2 tests containing 2 assertions.
0 failures, 1 errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured this one out. It was failing due to my use of a [specter macro](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter/wiki/List-of-Macros#select-one) + navigator. I’m not sure how. But somehow this messes up [test.check](https://github.com/clojure/test.check) generators.

I’m assuming it’s some kind of strange interplay that’s unworkable with Clojurescript’s macro system.